# SQL Select PIVOT on one column but select other columns tied to pivot field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table I am using PIVOT on, which it works and returns the data for the pivot columns correctly, but I have other columns in the row I want to tie to the pivoted column.

**Example:**

```
ID, PhoneType (column to PIVOT), PhoneNumber (value to be pivoted), PhoneAttribute1, PhoneAttribute2, PhoneAttribute3.

1, Cell, 123456789, call, dontcall, pleasecall
1, work, 123456780, call2, dontcall2, pleasecall2
2, Home, 123456782, call2, dontcall2, pleasecall2
```

When I pivot the data (without the attribute columns) I get the output:

```
ID, CELL, Work, Home
1, 123456789, 123456780, NULL
2, NULL, NULL, 123456782
```

Which is correct but I want to add the other attributcolumns to the list so it ties each attribute to each phone number, like this:

```
ID, CELL, Work, Home, CELLPhoneAttribute1, CELLPhoneAttribute2, CELLPhoneAttribute3, WorkPhoneAttribute1, WorkPhoneAttribute2, WorkPhoneAttribute3,......
```

Is this possible?

I can do it with joins, but that can be cumbersome, and if I add more phonetypes, it would get even larger.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use conditional aggregation. In that case, no joins are necessary. Not the prettiest, but not hard to extend either.

```
select id,
       max(case when phone_type = 'Cell' then PhoneNumber end) as CELL,
       max(case when phone_type = 'work' then PhoneNumber end) as Work,
       max(case when phone_type = 'Home' then PhoneNumber end) as Home,
       max(case when phone_type = 'Cell' then PhoneAttribute1 end) as CELLPhoneAttribute1,
       max(case when phone_type = 'Cell' then PhoneAttribute2 end) as CELLPhoneAttribute2,
       max(case when phone_type = 'Cell' then PhoneAttribute3 end) as CELLPhoneAttribute3,
       max(case when phone_type = 'work' then PhoneAttribute1 end) as WorkPhoneAttribute1,
       max(case when phone_type = 'work' then PhoneAttribute2 end) as WorkPhoneAttribute2,
       max(case when phone_type = 'work' then PhoneAttribute3 end) as WorkPhoneAttribute3,
       max(case when phone_type = 'Home' then PhoneAttribute1 end) as HomePhoneAttribute1,
       max(case when phone_type = 'Home' then PhoneAttribute2 end) as HomePhoneAttribute2,
       max(case when phone_type = 'Home' then PhoneAttribute3 end) as HomePhoneAttribute3
  from tbl
 group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware this is not possible without using several regular joins.

What is the intended purpose of the resulting table of data?  Most reporting tools will let you do this grouping easily.  For example, combining row level and column level grouping within SSRS on a table matrix.

Comment: I need to use the data as part of a process to run filters and other manipulation on.  So a basic report wont work for these purposes

Comment: I think that if you can tell us more about that process a better solution can be found.  Generally speaking, trying to do what you are doing in SQL is rarely the best approach and can usually be done without, by changing your approach to the whole task.